# Opengl lighting- Specular higlight is colored?

Tags: opengl

I am facing a problem, My specular lighting is also coloured.. In my code I have mentioned, 
LightColor = ambient+diffuse+specular;

FragColor = BodyColor * LightColor;

//My specular light appears in the same color as that of body. Can somebody help me to fix this?

Comment: we need some code to help you, because you don't give us any precision on how `specular` is computed

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is the same color as the body - because you're doing a component-wise multiplication of `BodyColor` against `LightColor`. That means the specular highlight is influenced by the body color just as much as the diffuse and ambient are, which is obviously not what you want.

For example, if `BodyColor` is `[1.0 0.0 0.0]`, aka red (let's ignore alpha for argument's sake), and the combined light color is `[0.8 0.8 0.8]`, aka light gray, then:

```
FragColor = [1.0 0.0 0.0] * [0.8 0.8 0.8] = [0.8 0.0 0.0]
```

Which is not-quite-full red.

You can never escape the output being based upon the body color with the math you have. At least, without going through a convoluted division, and even then, it won't work with zero components.

There are a number of solutions to your problem, of varying degrees of accuracy, but the simplest (and what it seems you are trying to do) is to multiply the body by the combined lighting except specular, and add specular:

```
FragColor = BodyColor * (LightDiffuse + Ambient) + LightSpecular;
```

Specular lighting represents a fundamentally different phenomena than diffuse/ambient: it is the light bounced off of the surface, or out of a thin layer at the surface (as colored specular usually represents). As such, it should not be multiplied against the color of the body. It might be multiplied against a separate surface specular color, but usually is not.

You still need some rather complex linear algebra to arrive at the `LightSpecular` term, since it is not applied flat to the surface, but depends upon the angle of the camera to the object and from the object to the light. Since you didn't ask, I am assuming you have that; although since you probably don't, I will suggest that there are many pages about that topic all over the internet.